# Error message: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I have read the previous questions with similar titles, none seem to provide me with an answer to this particular situation. I am receiving the error mentioned above on a specific functionality. I am not sure what is making it pop up. This is my first development so, unless it is specific to resolving the bug, please leave out the fact that I should be using PDO or mysqli.

this is the function i am trying to instantiate. when the sql command is executed in isolation, it returns the proper results.

```
public function search_for_candidates_by_technology($technology, $seniority){
    $technology = $this->real_escape_string($technology);
    $seniority = $this->real_escape_string($seniority);
    $this->query("SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE technology LIKE ". $technology ."  AND         seniority LIKE ". $seniority ."");
```

}

The class to which the function belongs is tecnoDB
In the actual page where I am trying to instantiate, this is the code:

```
<form name="buscarBase" action="buscarCV.php" method="POST">Que technologia:<input         type="text" name="usertech" value=""/><br/>
        Que seniority:<input type="text" name="userSeniority" value="" />
        <input type="submit" name="buscar" value="Buscar"  />
        <input type="submit" name="back" value="Panel de Control"/>
    </form>
    <table border="black">
        <tr><th>Technology</th><th>Seniority</tr>
    <?php
    $search = tecnoDB::getInstance()->search_for_candidates_by_technology($_POST['usertech'], $_POST['userSeniority']);
                while($searchResult = mysql_fetch_array($search)){
                        echo "<tr><td>" . htmlentities($searchResult['technology']) ."</td>";
                        echo "<td>". htmlentities($searchResult['seniority']) . "</td></tr>";
                }
                        ?>
    </table>
```

The error is coming on the line:  while($searchResult = mysql_fetch_array($search))....
That makes me think that the problem is that $search is not being created as an instance. Any ideas?

This is my first project and first question, please be gentle.

Comment: I am not sure as to why you are using 2 submit buttons?

Comment: post the code of your TecnoDB class. This doesn't actually tell us anything. But anyway, $search is apparently null. For a mysql_fetch_array call it should be a `mysql resource` (not an object, and definitly not `null`)

Comment: @Adarsh - One reason: it allows you to send different values to your form handling code. For example, you could have two submit buttons for handling user requests: one to approve the request, one to reject it.

Comment: I am posting my tecnoDB class as well as the entire code of the buscarCV page. to answer Adarse, I have two submit buttons because one will return the user to the control panel and the other will execute the search. here goes the code for buscarCV:

Comment: Can't post code yet, I will post when it lets me. I am wondering if an exit i have in the code at the top of the page is ending the session and thus not letting $instantiate...

Comment: Every question you read has the same answer. Your query is failing. Even in your answer you're still not doing any kind of proper error checking.

Comment: MikeB - in my answer I actually have an error check.  the code below is the original code that was problematic. the working code has an if statement that checks if the existence of $variable1. if the statement evaluates false, it echos a mysql_error. if the statement exists, it shows the results. The mysql_error is not appearing and the warning errors are not showing. I reiterate THE CODE BELOW IS NOT THE CORRECTED CODE. IT IS THE PROBLEMATIC CODE.

Comment: @MikeB - You were correct my friend. It was a silly mistake. Obviously as I mention above, this is my first development. I am a recruiter who has been drawn to development and feels more suited for actual development than recruiting. I have crossed from the dark-side so to speak. I also now have the results posting properly after getting the query punctuation squared away. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score -2):

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        session_start();
if (!array_key_exists("user", $_SESSION)) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
require_once("Includes/tecnoDB.php");
    $company_id = tecnoDB::getInstance()->get_company_id_by_name($_SESSION['user']);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        if (array_key_exists("back", $_POST)) {
           header('Location: companyControlPanel.php' ); 
           exit;
        } 
else{
$service_user = tecnoDB::getInstance()->verify_service_status($company_id);    
         $access = $service_user->fetch_row();       
         if (array_key_exists ("buscar", $_POST)){
                   if($access[0] < 2 ){
               header("Location: selectServicePackage.php" );                
               exit;
                   }
                             }

}
}

        // put your code here ?>
        <form name="buscarBase" action="buscarCV.php" method="POST">Que tecnologia:<input type="text" name="usertech" value=""/><br/>
            Que seniority:<input type="text" name="userSeniority" value="" />
            <input type="submit" name="buscar" value="Buscar"  />
            <input type="submit" name="back" value="Panel de Control"/>
        </form>
        <table border="black">
            <tr><th>Technology</th><th>Seniority</tr>
        <?php
        $search = tecnoDB::getInstance()->search_for_candidates_by_technology($_POST['usertech'], $_POST['userSeniority']);
                    while($searchResult = mysql_fetch_array($search)){
                            echo "<tr><td>" . htmlentities($searchResult['technology']) ."</td>";
                            echo "<td>". htmlentities($searchResult['seniority']) . "</td></tr>";
                    }
                            ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>



here goes the tecnoDB class:

    class tecnoDB extends mysqli {


    // single instance of self shared among all instances
    private static $instance = null;


    // db connection config vars
    private $user = "phpuser";
    private $pass = "phpuserpw";
    private $dbName = "tecnosearch";
    private $dbHost = "localhost";

     //This method must be static, and must return an instance of the object if the object
 //does not already exist.
     public static function getInstance() {
   if (!self::$instance instanceof self) {
     self::$instance = new self;
   }
   return self::$instance;
 }

 // The clone and wakeup methods prevents external instantiation of copies of the Singleton class,
 // thus eliminating the possibility of duplicate objects.
     public function __clone() {
   trigger_error('Clone is not allowed.', E_USER_ERROR);
 }
 public function __wakeup() {
   trigger_error('Deserializing is not allowed.', E_USER_ERROR);
 }

 // private constructor
    private function __construct() {
    parent::__construct($this->dbHost, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbName);
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    parent::set_charset('utf-8');
}

public function get_company_id_by_name($name) {

    $name = $this->real_escape_string($name);

    $company = $this->query("SELECT id FROM company WHERE name = '"

            . $name . "'");
    if ($company->num_rows > 0){
        $row = $company->fetch_row();
        return $row[0];
    } else
        return null;
}

public function get_searches_by_company_id($company_id) {
    return $this->query("SELECT id, description, technology FROM searches WHERE company_id=" . $company_id);
}

public function create_company ($name, $password){
    $name = $this->real_escape_string($name);
    $password = $this->real_escape_string($password);
    $this->query("INSERT INTO company (name, password) VALUES ('" . $name . "', '" . $password . "')");
}

public function verify_company_credentials ($name, $password){
   $name = $this->real_escape_string($name);

   $password = $this->real_escape_string($password);
   $result = $this->query("SELECT 1 FROM company
               WHERE name = '" . $name . "' AND password = '" . $password . "'");
   return $result->data_seek(0);   
}

public function verify_service_status ($company_id){
    $company_id = $this->real_escape_string($company_id);
    $service = $this->query("SELECT service FROM company WHERE id = '". $company_id ."'");
    return $service;   
}

function insert_search($company_id, $description, $technology){
    $description = $this->real_escape_string($description);
    $technology = $this->real_escape_string($technology);
    $this->query("INSERT INTO searches (company_id, description, technology)" . 
                       " VALUES (" . $company_id . ", '" . $description . "','" .$technology. "')");
}

public function search_for_candidates_by_technology($technology, $seniority){
    $technology = $this->real_escape_string($technology);
    $seniority = $this->real_escape_string($seniority);
    $this->query("SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE technology LIKE ". $technology ."  AND seniority LIKE ". $seniority ."");
}
}
?>
```

I fixed the bug by setting the query in search_for_candidates_by_technology = $variable and returning the variable as well as in the actual page requiring the file where I have this function specified. I set the instance of the search_for_candidates_by_technology equal to $variable1 and created another object as the result of $variable1->get_array; . My error messages are now gone but the results are not appearing in the search. I am assuming because the action is on the same page and it causes the page to reload and when it reloads it essentially is resetting. I am looking at using an AJAX to show the results instead but I have never used asynchronous javascript and have only briefly seen XMLs. Any pointers or ideas that won't require AJAX?